# Sending phaser image over websockets

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, socket.io, phaser-framework

So basically I want to send an image loaded by phaser over websockets. (socket.io) However it seems that an image has some kind of recursive/circular structure in it and therefore I can't send it (or convert it to a string).

Now I think I have already found the point where the problem occurs but I don't know how to avoid it.

Part of the structure of a picture:
[snippet out of the console in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwqSx.png)


Code:

```
Game.prototype = {

preload: function(){
    let me = this;
    console.log("loading images...");
    me.game.load.image('dragon', '/dragon.png');
    me.game.load.image('kraken', '/kraken.png');
    me.game.load.image('godzilla', '/godzilla.png');
    me.game.load.image('alien', '/alien.png');
},
```

---

Is it somehow possible to send an image over websockets like this or do I have to get the key of the picture out of the structure and send it?

**EDIT:**
Did it by getting the key, which is a better solution anyways i guess.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should open a WebSocket (ws) before anything else. The ws promotion will use a different schema (ws://) over the same TCP/IP connection. Use the Dev Console to watch the network transactions.
2. Socket.io must be used on both the server and client-side of the WebSocket "tube". Quote from "Phaser Multiplayer Gaming Systems" page 84, “Socket.IO is not a WebSocket library with fallback options to other real-time protocols. It is a custom real-time transport protocol implementation on top of other real-time protocols. Its protocol negotiation parts cause a client supporting standard WebSocket to not be able to contact a Socket.IO server. And a Socket.IO implementing client cannot talk to a non-Socket.IO based WebSocket or Long Polling Comet server. Therefore, Socket.IO requires using the Socket.IO libraries on both client and server side.”